# Get comment sub-comments when only one sub-comment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have comments table where has `parent_id`
This is Comment table `sub_comments` relation.

```
public function sub_comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

This code return all comments with related all sub-comments

```
Comment::with('sub_comments')->get();
```

But I want to get all comments also sub-comments when sub-comments is single. That mean if comment have 2 or more comments for that comment I did not want get that sub-comments.
Now I use this code

```
$oneSubcommentCommentIds = Comment::has('sub_comments', '=', 1)->pluck('id');
Comment::with([
    'sub_comments' => function ($q) use ($oneSubcommentCommentIds) {
        $q->whereIn('parent_id', $oneSubcommentCommentIds);
    }
])->get();
```

but this make one additional query.

Comment: So you want to load all comments, but only load the relation `sub_comments` if there's a single `sub_comment`? That doesn't make sense, and you can't determine the count of the relation *without loading the relation*...

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 2):

<s>Try this:</s>

```
Comment::with('sub_comments')->has('sub_comments', '=', 1)->get();
```

---

## Update

Your question wasn't clear, I can't imagine another way to doing this without previosly loaded the relationship or the count of the relationship.. so I'd do this:

```
// First get all your comments with an aditional count field
$comments = Comments::withCount('sub_comments')->get();

// separate the ones with just one sub_comment from the rest
list($oneSubComment, $theRest) = $collection->partition(function ($comment) {
    return $comment->sub_comments_count == 1;
});

// Then load the relationship on just the selected elements
$oneSubComment->load('sub_comments');

// re-join the collection
$comments = $oneSubComment->union($theRest);
```

What am I doing here?

1. Adding an additional field to each `$comment` with the [relationship count](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) (it should be something like `sub_comments_count`)
2. Partition the resulting collection in two parts: the ones with one comment and the rest. Using the [`partition()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-partition) method.
3. [Lazy eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) the collection.
4. Re-joining the two collections using the [`union()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-union) method.

Comment: This must be get only comments which has one sub-comment. But I want to get all comments

Comment: @Davit I've updated my answer. I have not test it but it should work or at least guide you to get your desired output.

Comment: Your solution must be work But this is also make 2 query. I want to use only 1 query

Comment: Yeah, I'd also like to know how to do this in just one query but I can't imagine how. You could also just load the relationship for all the comments and then hide them in your view to match your needs.

Comment: I test your code. It is working(upvote). But I prefer do optimize query and make only 1 query